# What would be the FBD/external forces on the floor of a lift moving with acceleration a downwards?

Tags: newtonian-mechanics, forces, reference-frames, free-body-diagram

We know that external forces are held responsible for acceleration produced and we represent external forces on a choosen system using FBD. For the case of an life moving downwards with acceleration 'a' having a box of mass m placed inside of it. Now the mass m will have and weight 'mg' acting downwards and an Normal rxn N by the lifts floor.

So the NLM eqn is ,

$$mg - N = ma \tag{1}
$$

But when I draw the FBD for the lifts floor the only external force is N so it's NLM eqn should be

$$N = ma$$

Which contradicts the eqn (1) ,
What am I doing wrong ?

Comment: There are other forces acting on the lift.  For instance, gravity acting downwards and the tension force of the cable pulling upwards.

Comment: What do FBD and NLM mean?

Answer (score 1):

I think the problem with the second equation is that your is that this equation is made when your considering yourself inside the lift and if that the case then the there also a pseudo force applied of the box as you yourself are in motion (non -inertial frame of reference)

[https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Non-inertial_reference_frame#:~:text=A%20non%2Dinertial%20reference%20frame,detect%20a%20non%2Dzero%20acceleration](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Non-inertial_reference_frame#:%7E:text=A%20non%2Dinertial%20reference%20frame,detect%20a%20non%2Dzero%20acceleration).

More about pseudo force here  https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Fictitious_force

now if we correct the equation it will be as follows

$mg = N+ ma$

Which on further simplifying give you

$$mg - N = ma$$

Hope this helps